# Non-Nullable Property Must Contain A Non-Null Value

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Is there any way to handle the "Non-Nullable Property Must Contain A Non-Null Value" alert in Visual Studio for mac.
Well, I can't find a way to disable it by removing the line from the csproj project file or configuration.
These warnings are in my database models and views and the idea is to proceed in the best way.
It should be said that I am using .Net 6.0

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read this question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm assuming you have nullable reference types enabled. There's a number of ways you can deal with this.

1. Explicitly initialize those properties to the default or a known value either at the property declaration directly or within a constructor.

   ```
   public class SomeType
   {
       public string SomeProperty { get; set; } = default!;
   }
   ```
2. Disable nullable reference types for the entire file or section.

   ```
   #nullable disable // at the top of the file

   #nullable restore // after the block of code you wanted to temporarily disable
   ```
3. Disable nullable reference types for the entire project.
   Remove or change the `<Nullable>` setting in your project file. (It defaults to enabled in .NET 6)

I would try to stick to #1 exclusively. Leave #3 alone if the intention is to make the transition.

Comment: Hi @Jeff-Mercado, your assumption is probably correct since .NET 6 has nullable enabled by default (which is a change from previous).

Comment: I am confused. What if the value of the property is compulsory to have? I don't want it to be nullable?

Comment: @SubliminalHash If that's the case, you would either have to provide a non-null value here for initialization instead or create a constructor and provide a value from there. Either way, the compiler is trying to help you set that and if you're not ready to set it, then this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks. So an application compulsory field 'FullName' will have to be a string? or a value will have to be set to it e.g. String.Empty. What about null! ?

Comment: @SubliminalHash Null should be fine, you will just need to remember to set it later before you use it.

Comment: What's the meaning behind "= default!;" tried to google it but didn't find an answer. Thanks for the answer here.

Comment: @Deepak `default` in that context (shorthand for `default(string)`) is the default value for the type. It's equivalent to `null!`. The `!` tells the compiler to ignore the nullability checks it would normally have done.